# Why is the first arg in stdarg.h a register?

Tags: c, gcc, centos

stdarg.h warns:

> Warning: First arg is in a register,
>   stdarg.h cannot take its address

Why would the first argument will be stored in register?

Comment: Your question is about specific implementation, please specify OS and Compiler.

Comment: It depends on the ABI, which in turn is determined by the CPU family and OS that you are using.

Comment: stdarg.h does not produce warnings. Your compiler does, based on some code you compile. Please post the code, and the command line you use to compile that code.

Comment: @nos: See here, the `#warning` at the bottom of the file: http://www.koders.com/c/fid3770C5C5A9A03BA4F21F44458FA45D90B84D550C.aspx?s=cdefs

Answer (score 2):

Some calling conventions (eg fastcall) pass the first few arguments in registers instead of placing them on the stack. However, this makes taking the address of these variables impossible, and most implementations of variadic functions rely on this. Therefore, a compiler might additionally place the arguments on the stack as well as in registers or use a different calling convention for variadic functions.